# Error related to decimal format when spring application try make a payment with PayPal

Tags: spring, paypal, decimalformat

In my current spring project, I recently add support to paypal in it. But right now, the payment is only finished when I hard coded the amount values in the source code. The method in my service class which handle the payment process mount the variables where this values are stored in this way:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    Float value = valor(cliente);
    String svalue = df.format(value).replace(',', '.');

    System.out.println("valor = "+value);
    System.out.println("valor (String) = "+svalue);

    Details details = new Details();
    details.setShipping("0");
    details.setSubtotal( svalue );
    details.setTax("0");

    Amount amount = new Amount();
    amount.setCurrency("BRL");
    amount.setTotal( svalue );
    amount.setDetails(details);

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setAmount(amount);
    transaction.setDescription("compra no site Loja on-line");
```

When I run the application and try make a payment, I get this error:

```
GRAVE: Error code : 400 with response : {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].amount.total","issue":"Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands separator ',', limited to 7 digits before the decimal point"},{"field":"transactions[0].amount.details.subtotal","issue":"Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands separator ',', limited to 7 digits before the decimal point"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"9639791c47625"}
```

Someone can tell me What I missing here? I would think the use of `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");`  to format my subtotal and total value should be enough, but apparently I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like when you pass the savlue in `" amount.setTotal( svalue );"` it is of the String type .

I will advise you do change this to  :

```
 amount.setTotal( Float.parseFloat(svalue));
```

and here also :

`details.setSubtotal( svalue );`  to  `details.setSubtotal( Float.parseFloat(svalue) );`

Comment: but the methods `setTotal(...)` and `setSubtotal(...)` requires a Strig parameter, not a Float.